# Why does ViewController with ScrollViewDelegate won't show me anything in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I recently switched from Objective C to Swift, so I am not familiar with finding mistakes in my own algorithm. I would like to understand what am I missing here.

I've got `ViewController` with `ScrollView` added. Everything compiles and runs, no `SIGARBT`'s or so, but It won't display the desired images. Every `IBOutlet` is connected propely in its place.

Below is the function for all of the UI Elements:

```
func UIUpdate() {

    guard let imageContent = content as? ImageContent,
        pages = imageContent.pages?.array as? [Image] else {

            return
    }

    self.pages = pages
    self.mainTitleLabel.text = imageContent.title

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pages.count


    let imageWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width// - 20

    self.scrollView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
    self.scrollView.frame.size.height = imageWidth / 1.883

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageWidth *
        CGFloat(pages.count), self.scrollView.frame.size.height)

    for (index, page) in pages.enumerate() {

        autoreleasepool {
            guard let imageData = page.image, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }

            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            self.addConstraints(toImageView: imageView, atIndex: index, lastIndex: pages.count - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

`Image` class is where images and titles are parsed. So this class is perfectly fine, because I have been using it in another project. This method is the only one called for getting those images. There are methods though, but I think they've got nothing to do with my problem.

Could You guys show me the mistake! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you use Xcode's View Debugging feature, can you see the size and placement of the views at runtime?

Comment: I checked, I can see `ScrollView` but there's lack of `UIImageView` although it's listed on View Hierarchy.

Comment: If you select it in the view hierarchy, then use the Size Inspector, it should show the view bounds and any constraints being applied.

Comment: https://s9.postimg.org/j3qvnh7fj/merged_Screen_Shot.jpg

They have no constraints, what's weird because I added them in addConstraints.

Comment: try to print the UIImage to the command line to see if everything's ok there and also run isHidden = false on the UIImages just in case + try resizing them again manually with image.frame = CGRect(...) to make sure that you don't have a problem with the sizing. They are probably just out of bounds and can't be seen on screen in the simulator => that is why you can still see them in the view hierarchy

Comment: There's some breakthrough though... I added breakpoint on beginning of this method and `Print(UIImage)`. And after `guard let` nothing is initialized. Why so?

Comment: Well if you can actually see them in the view hierarchy: the x,y coordinates are wrong at runtime and the images are shown somewhere outside of your screen. That's my best guess atm. Try image.draw(..) and manually change CGRect to the width/height + x,y which should definitely show up e.g. x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height:300

Comment: Ok, I am not sure now about that. I provided one more problem in my answer above.